# How to scale smoothed image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a data image. I smoothed it with a C# code, by convolution with a normalized 2D Gaussian function.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. I created the Gaussian kernel as a `9x9` matrix, valued as:

   ```
   (1/sigma*sqrt(2*PI))exp(-x^2-y^2)/(2*sigma^2).
   ```

   For a `9x9` matrix, what should be the range of `x` and `y`? `-4 to 4` or `-0.4 to 0.4`? how should I find it out?
2. After smoothing, they data values are mapped to another scale? How should I rescale them? what is the key? I mean what should be fixed? variance? mean? or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `-4 to 4` or `-0.4 to 0.4`. It doesn't matters. The fact is, you scales size of kernel by changing the range of `x` and `y` in your 9x9 matrix. What really matters is the `sigma` value.

I am not very sure what do you expect from this `9x9` kernel. But it is suggested that if you want an accurate enough result. The size of the matrix should be as large as 6*sigma (in the case you choose `-4 to 4` as the range). If you create a 100*100 matrix with the same sigma value, the result image should be the same, almost.

After convolution, you need no further process on the data once you ensure the **sum of the values in your kernel matrix equals to 1**.

Comment: Thanks for good points. Now I now how to determine the range of x and y. As I told I want to smooth a data image with this gaussian kernel.

Comment: When making kernel matrix values, I multiply them with 1/(sigma*sqrt(2*PI), according to have a normalized gaussian. So why is it necessary to have "sum of values of kernel matrix equals to 1"?

Comment: @MahsaRahimi Keep such a sum equals to 1 ensures that the result data's mean value is similar to one of the original data. It is true that the integral of your Gaussian function is 1. But it is not the case for your kernel matrix since the matrix is just a bunch of sample points on the Gaussian function.